getCellValue don’t take all the rows
I'm programming a code that searches a table that contains around 250 rows from which I only need 3 columns, one for comparison and the other two that will ultimately be inserted into excel, basically it is that I first extract all the values ​​from the three columns in rowValues ​​and then I do the filtering using the ZWNUMMER column to find which rows have to be saved in the Values ​​matrix, this last one ends up being filled with empty rows as well, so before inserting it into excel I filter again to create the filteredValues ​​matrix that contains only the data that I need. The problem is that checking part by part I find that apparently getCellValue does not extract all the rows, which I already verified, I have tried other alternatives to getCellValue but my SAP GUI seems to only be able to handle this, I would like a second opinion because I ran out of ideas.
Here’s the code. Thanks for the help.
    With session
        ' Browse to the table
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtIEANL-ANLAGE").SetFocus
        .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
        .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[34]").press
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsMYTABSTRIP/tabpPUSH10").Select
        ' Table identifier
        Set dataRange = .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsMYTABSTRIP/tabpPUSH10/ssubSUB10:SAPLEADS2:0200/cntlCONTROL_AREA10/shellcont/shell")
       
        rowCount = dataRange.rowCount
        
        ReDim rowValues(1 To rowCount, 1 To 3)
       
        For i = 0 To rowCount - 1
       
            cellValueADAT = dataRange.GetCellValue(i, "ADAT")
            cellValueZWSTAND_DISP = dataRange.GetCellValue(i, "ZWSTAND_DISP")
            cellValueZWNUMMER = dataRange.GetCellValue(i, "ZWNUMMER")
           
            rowValues(i + 1, 1) = cellValueADAT
            rowValues(i + 1, 3) = cellValueZWSTAND_DISP
            rowValues(i + 1, 2) = cellValueZWNUMMER
        Next i
        
        ' Specific value
        ZWNUMMERvalue = 3
        
        ReDim Values(1 To rowCount, 1 To 3)
        For i = 0 To rowCount - 1
            If rowValues(i + 1, 2) = ZWNUMMERvalue Then
                Values(i + 1, 1) = rowValues(i + 1, 1)
                Values(i + 1, 2) = rowValues(i + 1, 3)
        End If
        Next i
        
        nonEmptyCount = 0
        For i = 1 To rowCount
            If Not IsEmpty(Values(i, 1)) Or Not IsEmpty(Values(i, 2)) Then
                nonEmptyCount = nonEmptyCount + 1
            End If
        Next i

        ReDim filteredValues(1 To nonEmptyCount, 1 To 2)
        nonEmptyCount = 0
        For i = 1 To rowCount
            If Not IsEmpty(Values(i, 1)) Or Not IsEmpty(Values(i, 2)) Then
                nonEmptyCount = nonEmptyCount + 1
                filteredValues(nonEmptyCount, 1) = Values(i, 1)
                filteredValues(nonEmptyCount, 2) = Values(i, 2)
            End If
        Next i

        If nonEmptyCount > 0 Then
            ws.Range("A3").Resize(nonEmptyCount, 2).value = filteredValues
        End If
        
    End With

